# If the covariance of two uniformly distributed variables equals zero, are they independent?

Tags: correlation, covariance, independence

If the covariance of two uniformly distributed variables equals zero, are they independent?

X,Y~U(-1,1) If E(XY)=E(X)E(Y), then can I say that they are independent?

Thank you.

Comment: Note that $\mathbb E[X]=\mathbb E[Y]=0$, so $\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y)=0$ implies that $\mathbb E[XY]=0$.

Comment: One would expect the answer to be no, but if it is yes then it is because of the particular distribution under consideration. To prove it is no, the most direct way would be to try to find a nonlinear function $f$ such that when $X \sim U(-1,1)$, $f(X) \sim U(-1,1)$ but $E[Xf(X)]=0$. Perhaps $f(x)=\begin{cases} x & x \in [-a,a] \\ -x & x \not \in [-a,a] \end{cases}$, where $a \in (0,1)$ is chosen such that $E[Xf(X)]=0$, will do the job?